# Vagrant ssh authentication failure

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualbox, private-key, vagrantfile

The problem with ssh authentication:

```
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: bridged
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Error: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Error: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Error: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Error: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Error: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Error: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Error: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Error: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Error: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

I can `Ctrl+C` out of the authentication loop and then successfully ssh in manually.

I performed the following steps on the guest box:

- Enabled `Remote Login` for `All Users`.
- Created the `~/.ssh` directory with `0700` permissions.
- Created the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file with `0600` permissions.
- Pasted [this public key](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/keys/vagrant.pub)
  into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

I've also tried using a private (hostonly) network instead of the public (bridged) network, using this line in the Vagrantfile:

`config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.16.177.7"`

I get the same output (except `Adapter 2: hostonly`) but then cannot ssh in manually.

I also tried `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.100"`.

I also tried setting `config.ssh.password` in the Vagrantfile. This does output `SSH auth method: password` but still doesn't authenticate.

And I also tried rebuilding the box and rechecking all the above.

It looks like [others have had success with this configuration](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/HKL0FXR6QmE), so there must be something I'm doing wrong.

I [found this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575261/vagrant-stuck-connection-timeout-retrying) and enabled the GUI, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your first network interface is NAT. The other second network interface can be anything you want when you're building box. Don't forget the Vagrant user, as discussed in the Google thread.

Good luck.

Answer (score 189):

**For general information:** by default to ssh-connect you may simply use

user: `vagrant` password: `vagrant`

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/base.html#quot-vagrant-quot-user

**First, try:** to see what vagrant `insecure_private_key` is in your machine config

```
$ vagrant ssh-config
```

Example:

```
$ vagrant ssh-config
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile C:/Users/konst/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/ssh_config.html

**Second, do:**
Change the contents of file `insecure_private_key` with the contents of your personal system *private key*

**Or use:**
Add it to the Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
end
```

1. `config.ssh.private_key_path` is your local private key
2. Your private key must be available to the local ssh-agent. You can check with `ssh-add -L`. If it's not listed, add it with `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
3. Don't forget to add your public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the Vagrant VM. You can do it by copy-and-pasting or using a tool like [ssh-copy-id](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id) (user: `root` password: `vagrant` port: 2222) `ssh-copy-id '-p 2222 root@127.0.0.1'`

**If still does not work try this:**

1. Remove `insecure_private_key` file from `c:\Users\USERNAME\.vagrant.d\insecure_private_key`
2. Run `vagrant up` (vagrant will be generate a new `insecure_private_key` file)

**In other cases, it is helpful to just set [forward_agent](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html) in** `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
   config.ssh.forward_agent = true
end
```

**Useful:**

Configurating **git** may be with [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com)

After setup this program and creating personal system *private key* will be in yours profile path: `c:\users\USERNAME\.ssh\id_rsa.pub`

**PS:** Finally - suggest you look at [Ubuntu on Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide)

Comment: in my case it was problem because of `config.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"` had to remove this line to make provisioning work

Comment: All of this worked but I also had to remove my entry in known hosts. I was having issues when moving locations and logging in.

Comment: @shilovk +1 Thank you, thank you, thank you very much. The "Second, do" did the trick. Again, thank you very much man.

Comment: This one pointed me in the right direction, in my case all I had to do was to delete the .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key file and after running vagrant up it replaced the file with the correct one - I would backup the file just in case

Comment: The first and most important step is to check your BIOS settings, make sure Virtualization is enabled.

Comment: Change the contents of file insecure_private_key with the contents of your personal system private key,  for me it was enough. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What worked for me was to delete the insecure_private_key and then doing *any* vagrant command,  such as vagrant destroy,  will regenerate the key.   How I got in this state might have something to do with swapping keys around trying to use the plain ssh patch that we have to do with Windows/Cygwin these days.

Answer (score 89):

None of the above worked for me. Somehow the box had the wrong public key added in the vagrant user *authorised_keys* file.

If you can still ssh on the box with the vagrant password (password is vagrant),  i.e.

```
ssh vagrant@localhost -p 2222
```

then copy the public key content from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant.pub to the authorised_keys file with the following command

```
echo "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA6NF8iallvQVp22WDkTkyrtvp9eWW6A8YVr+kz4TjGYe7gHzIw+niNltGEFHzD8+v1I2YJ6oXevct1YeS0o9HZyN1Q9qgCgzUFtdOKLv6IedplqoPkcmF0aYet2PkEDo3MlTBckFXPITAMzF8dJSIFo9D8HfdOV0IAdx4O7PtixWKn5y2hMNG0zQPyUecp4pzC6kivAIhyfHilFR61RGL+GPXQ2MWZWFYbAGjyiYJnAmCP3NOTd0jMZEnDkbUvxhMmBYSdETk1rRgm+R4LOzFUGaHqHDLKLX+FIPKcF96hrucXzcWyLbIbEgE98OHlnVYCzRdK8jlqm8tehUc9c9WhQ== vagrant insecure public key" > .ssh/authorized_keys
```

When done exit the VM and try vagrant ssh again. It should work now.

Comment: run `vagrant reload` after updating the authorized_keys file. Vagrant will auto detect the insecure key and re-generate it for you. Should work afterwards.

Answer (score 49):

If you experience this issue on vagrant 1.8.5, then check out this thread on github:

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7610

It's caused basically by a permission issue, the workaround is just

```
vagrant ssh 
password: vagrant 
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
exit
```

then

```
vagrant reload
```

FYI: this issue only affects CentOS, Ubuntu works fine.

Comment: Let say I have 5 machines for one vagrant file. Everytime I rerun I need to do it for each machine. I there fix this permanently for given vagrant setup using centos?

Comment: Just had to upgrade vagrant to version 1.8.6 use to have 1.8.5 where bug presisted

Answer (score 44):

Run the following commands in guest machine/VM:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant.pub -O ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown -R vagrant:vagrant ~/.ssh
```

Then do vagrant halt. This will remove and regenerate your private keys.

(These steps assume you have already created or already have the ~/.ssh/ and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys directories under your home folder.)

Comment: didn't work for me.  Vagrant version 2.2.15 with ubuntu 20.04 guest.

Answer (score 27):

In my experience, this has been a surprisingly frequent problem with new vagrant machines. By far the easiest way to solve it, instead of altering the configuration itself, has been creating the required ssh keys manually on the client, then using the private key on the host.

1. Log in to vagrant machine: `vagrant ssh`, use default password `vagrant`.
2. Create ssh keys: for example, `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "vagrant"` ([as adviced by GitHub's relevant guide](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/)).
3. Rename the public key file (by default id_rsa.pub), overriding the old one: `mv .ssh/id_rsa.pub .ssh/authorized_keys`.
4. Reload ssh service in case needed: `sudo service ssh reload`.
5. Copy the private key file (by default id_rsa) to the host machine: for instance, use a fine combination of cat and clipboard, `cat .ssh/id_rsa`, paint and copy (better ways must exist, go invent one!).
6. Logout from the vagrant machine: `logout`.
7. Find the current private key used by vagrant by looking at its configuration: `vagrant ssh-config` (look for instance ÌdentityFile "/[...]/private_key".
8. Replace the current private key with the one you created at the host machine: for example, `nano /[...]/private_key` and paste from the clipboard, if all else fails. (***Note***, however, that if your private_key is not project specific but shared by multiple vagrant machines, you better configure the path yourself in order to not break other perfectly working machines! Changing the path is as simple as adding a line `config.ssh.private_key_path = "path/to/private_key"` into the Vagrantfile.) Furthermore, if you are using [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com) generated machine, you can store your private key to file `puphpet/files/dot/ssh/id_rsa` and it will be added to Vagrantfile's ssh config automatically.
9. Test the setup: `vagrant ssh` should now work.

Should that be the case, congratulate yourself, `logout`, run `vagrant provision` if needed and carry on with the meaningful task at hand.

If you still face problems, it may come handy to add verbose flag to ssh command to ease debugging. You can pass that (or any other option, for that matter) after double dash. For example, typing `vagrant ssh -- -v`. Feel free to add as many v's as you need, each will give you more information.

Comment: This answer helped me. Just to share my experience: Somehow (possibly during the installation of Capistrano but that's not confirmed) my authorized_key file had been deleted on my guest VM. Recreating it using these steps worked and I can now ssh in without password prompt. Thanks.

Comment: After removing both keys (public/private) from host machine, I was able to redo and resolve with this process

Comment: Using Git makes transferring that file content faster.

Comment: this one worked for me after anything else i had tried, failed.. thanks a lot!

Comment: This worked for me. The only thing I did different was using `ssh vagrant@10.0.0.0 -p 22 (password: vagrant)` to login to VM as `vagrant ssh` wasn't working for me. `10.0.0.0` is the private ip address I have set in my `vagrantfile`.

Comment: I used PHP's builtin web server to transfer the key from Virtualbox.

Answer (score 17):

Unable to run vagrant up because it gets stuck and times out? I recently had a "water in laptop incident" and had to migrate to a new one(on a MAC by the way). I successfully got all my projects up and running beside the one, which was using vagrant.

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8000 (guest) => 8877 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 8001 (guest) => 8878 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 8080 (guest) => 7777 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 (guest) => 2345 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5000 (guest) => 8855 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

It couldn't authenticate, retried again and again and eventually gave up.

---

**This is how I got it back in shape in 3 steps:**

1 - Find the `IdentityFile` used by Vagrant:

```
$ vagrant ssh-config

Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/ned/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

2 - Check the public key in the `IdentityFile`:

```
$ ssh-keygen -y -f <path-to-insecure_private_key>
```

It'd output something like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nyc2EAAA...9gE98OHlnVYCzRdK8jlqm8hQ==
```

3 - Log in to the Vagrant guest with the password `vagrant`:

```
ssh -p 2222 -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null vagrant@127.0.0.1
```

```
The authenticity of host '[127.0.0.1]:2222 ([127.0.0.1]:2222)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is dc:48:73:c3:18:e4:9d:34:a2:7d:4b:20:6a:e7:3d:3e.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:2222' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
vagrant@127.0.0.1's password: vagrant
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-31-generic x86_64)
...
```

**NOTE:** if vagrant guest is configured to disallow password authentication you need to open VBox' GUI, double click guest name, login as `vagrant/vagrant`, then `sudo -s` and edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and look for `PasswordAuthentication no` line (usually at the end of the file), replace `no` with `yes` and restart sshd (i.e. `systemctl reload sshd` or `/etc/init.d/sshd restart`).

4 - Add the public key to the `/home/vagrant/authorized_keys` file.

```sh
$ echo "ssh-rsa AA2EAAA...9gEdK8jlqm8hQ== vagrant" > /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

5 - Exit (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>) and stop the Vagrant guest and then bring it back up.

> **IMPORTANT** if you use any provisioning tools (i.e. Ansible etc) **disable** it before restarting your guest as Vagrant will think your guest is not provisioned because of use of insecure private key. It will reinstall the key and then run your provisioner!

```sh
$ vagrant halt
$ vagrant up
```

Hopefully you will have your arms in the air now...

I got this, with just a minor amend, from Ned Batchelders [article](https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OXA/pages/157802739/Vagrant+is+stuck+Authentication+failure.+Retrying...) - Ned you are a champ!

Comment: You sir are a genius, or Ned Batchelders is. Either way, it fixed my issue!

Comment: I thought this fixed it for me as well, however, a `vagrant destroy` followed by `vagrant up` failed to retain these changes.

MacOS Catalina/Big Sur caused me a ton of problems, but ultimately, uninstalling VirtualBox/Vagrant, making sure to delete leftover folders, and yet another clean install got me up and running again. For Catalina and up, I had to do the Kernel Extension (Kext) updates from this Vagrant wiki: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Mac%2520OS%2520X%2520build%2520instructions&sa=D&source=editors&ust=1624061160498000&usg=AOvVaw02udTpVoDzajEDX64IJFcD

Answer (score 11):

This can also happen if you're trying to force your VM to use a root user by default for SSH....

For example, a config like so in your Vagrantfile may cause this failure:

```
config.ssh.username = 'root'
config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'
config.ssh.insert_key = 'true'
```

Solution: Comment out those lines and try again!

Comment: for me only setting config.ssh.username = "vagrant" and config.ssh.password = "vagrant" did the trick

Answer (score 10):

Problem I was getting the ssh authentication errors, on a box I provisioned. The original was working ok.

The problem for me was I was missing a private key in `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key`. I copied the private key from the same relative location from the original box and Viola!

Comment: I would add, that as any good developer, we are checking in the `.vagrant` files into git... and as such, a quick `git checkout` of said file saves the day!

Answer (score 10):

I have found a way around the mess with the keys on Win 8.2 where I did not succeed with any of the methods mentioned here. It may be interesting that exactly the same combination of VirtualBox, Vagrant, and the box run on Win 7 Ultimate without any problems.

I switched to the password authentication by adding the following commands in Vagrantfile:

```
config.ssh.password = "vagrant"
config.ssh.insert_key = false
```

Note that I'm not sure that this is the only changes required because I already did:

1. I generated a new RSA key pair and changed authorized_keys file accordingly (all in the virtual machine, see the suggestions above and elsewhere)
2. I copied the private key to the same directory where Vagrantfile resides and added

   ```
    config.ssh.private_key_path = "./id_rsa"
   ```

But I believe that these changes were irrelevant. I spent a plenty of time trying, so I did not change the working configuration by obvious reasons :)

Answer (score 6):

for me, this was resolved by changing the permissions on .ssh folder in vagrant home directort (i.e. "~vagrant/.ssh"). I think I messed up the permissions when I was setting up ssh keys for my application.

It seems that 'authorized_keys' file must be 'rw' only for 'vagrant' user so "chmod 600 authorized_keys"; the same goes for the directory itself and its parent:

so:

```
chmod 600 authorized_keys
chmod 700 .
chmod 700 ..
```

It was only after I had *all* these permissions restored that vagrant ssh started to work again.

I think it's something to do with ssh security. It refuses to recognise certificates if they are any way accessible beyond the current user, so vagrants attempts to login are thus rejected.

Comment: I sometimes cannot change, just running sudo chmod 600 authorized_keys but it still leaves unchanged. I think this has something to do that it is shared on windows also.

Comment: Sometimes this happens if the directory is on a share, for instance `/vagrant/...`

Comment: In addition to my answer I'd like to vote for this answer. On another machine of mine it was exactly this problem - wrong owner of the /home/vagrant/.ssh directory. It was "root:root" but must be "vagrant:vagrant"

Answer (score 5):

If you are using **windows** and this issue come unexpectedly, please try the following code in configuration.

```
config.ssh.username = 'vagrant'
config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'
config.ssh.insert_key = 'true'
```

This basically uses the default vagrant configuration.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using default SSH setup in your VagrantFile and started seeing SSH authentication errors after re-associating your VM box due to crash, try replacing public key in your vagrant machine.

Vagrant replaces public key associated with insecure private key pair at each log out due to security reasons. If you didn't properly shut down your machine, public/private key pair can go out of sync, causing SSH authentication error.

To resolve this issue, simply load up the current insecure private key and then copy the public key pair into your VM's authorized_keys file.

Answer (score 3):

This has happened to me several times and the way I solved it was :

1. Check and make sure your Vagrantfile has the correct private key path :

   config.ssh.private_key_path = "/home/razvan/.ssh/id_rsa"
2. Execute  > vagrant ssh command in a linux terminal
3. On your vagrant machine go to

   cd /home/vagrant/.ssh

and check if the ssh key in the authorized_keys file is the same as the one you have on your local machine in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub. If not replace the one from your **vagrant** authorized_keys with the one on your **local machine** found in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.

4. Reload Vagrant :

   vagrant reload

Hope this helps someone else. Cheers!

Comment: I don't have ~/.ssh folder then what should i do  ??

Comment: @AshishKarpe create it with 700 permission and create an `authorized_keys` file with 600 permission inside.

Answer (score 3):

This might be the last answer in the list but this worked for me and I did not find this answer anywhere, I found it my self after 2 days of researches so you've better try this if nothing else worked for you until now.

In my case the problem came from my VirtualBox. I don't know for what reason an option was disabled and it should have been enabled.

[image]

As you can see in the image, there were some network problems with my VirtualBox and what I had to do in order to fix this problem was to select my machine, press on settings, network tab and after that make sure that the option Cable Connected was selected. In my case this option was not selected and I it failed at this step:

```
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key
```

First I thought that the port is already in use, after that I reinstalled Vagrant and I also tried other things but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

#### 1. Locate the private key in the host:

```js
vagrant ssh-config
#
```

Output:

```js
Host default
  ...
  Port 2222
  ...
  IdentityFile /home/me/.vagrant.d/[...]/virtualbox/vagrant_private_key
  ...
```

#### 2. Store the private key path and the port number in variables:

Use these two commands with the output from above:

```js
pk="/home/me/.vagrant.d/.../virtualbox/vagrant_private_key"
port=2222
#
```

#### 3. Generate a public key and upload it to the guest machine:

Copy/pasta, no changes needed:

```shell
ssh-keygen -y -f $pk > authorized_keys
scp -P $port authorized_keys vagrant@localhost:~/.ssh/
vagrant ssh -c "chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
rm authorized_keys
#
```

Comment: I had the described problem so many times, usually after packaging and then restoring the Vagrant box. What worked to me is adding the following configuration in order to instruct Vagrant to insert it's public key into the VM:
`config.ssh.username = "vagrant"; config.ssh.password = "vagrant"; config.ssh.insert_key = true`
But this time the above configuration did nothing. I don't really know why, tried to debug why the key is not inserted without luck. So I fallbacked to your solution and voila! It works!

Answer (score 2):

Mac Solution:

1. Added local ssh id_rsa key to vagrant private key

   vi /Users//.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key

   /Users//.ssh/id_rsa
2. copied public key /Users//.ssh/id_rsa.pub on vagrant box authorized_keys

`ssh vagrant@localhost -p 2222` (password: vagrant)
`ls -la`
`cd .ssh`

3. `chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
4. `vagrant reload`

Problem resolved.

Thanks to

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should remove the autogenerated insecure_private_key file, then regenerate this file by typing

```
vagrant ssh-config
```

then

```
vagrant halt
vagrant up
```

It should work

Comment: I tried this but still getting error is this because I am using Ubuntu Virtual Box VM inside that I am trying vagrant ?

Comment: #vagrant up Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat ==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key

Answer (score 1):

also could not get beyond:

default: SSH auth method: private key

When I used the VirtualBox GUI, it told me there was an OS processor mismatch.

To get vagrant up progressing further, in the BIOS settings I had to counter-intuitively:

Disable: Virtualisation

Enable: VT-X

Try toggling these setting in your BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue in the following manner.
1.  Create new SSH key using Git Bash

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "vagrant@localhost"
# Creates a new ssh key, using the provided email as a label
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
```

2. When you're prompted to "Enter a file in which to save the key," press Enter. This accepts the default file location.

   Enter a file in which to save the key (/Users/[you]/.ssh/id_rsa): [Press enter]
3. At the prompt, type a secure passphrase. You can leave empty and press enter if you do not need a passphrase.

   Enter a file in which to save the key (/Users/[you]/.ssh/id_rsa): [Press enter]
4. To connect to your Vagrant VM type following command

   ssh vagrant@localhost -p 2222

When you get following message type “yes” and press enter.

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

5. Now to establish a SSH connection type : $ vagrant ssh
6. Copy the host public key into authorized_keys file in Vagrant VM. For that, go to “Users/[you]/.ssh” folder and copy the content in id_rsa.pub file in host machine and past into “~/.ssh/authorized_keys” file in Vagrant VM.
7. Change permission on SSH folder and authorized_keys file in Vagrant VM
8. Restart vagrant with : $ vagrant reload

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution, in windows, go to the file Homestead/Vagrantfile and add these lines to connect with a username/password instead of a private key:

```
config.ssh.username = "vagrant"  
config.ssh.password = "vagrant"  
config.ssh.insert_key = false
```

So, finally part of the file will look like this :

```
if File.exists? homesteadYamlPath then
    settings = YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath))
elsif File.exists? homesteadJsonPath then
    settings = JSON.parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath))
end

config.ssh.username = "vagrant"  
config.ssh.password = "vagrant"  
config.ssh.insert_key = false 

Homestead.configure(config, settings)

if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
    config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath, privileged: false
end
```

Hope this help ..

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my solution:

```
rm /Users/myusername/.ssh/config
vagrant ssh-config >> /Users/myusername/.ssh/config
```

Somewhat similar to other proposed solutions here.

Answer (score 1):

If SSH to a Vagrant Box stalls, you can always enter the box by changing the Vagrantfile to

```
vb.gui = true
```

enter *vagrant* and *vagrant* again as a password.

In the VM, it is possible to check the logs of **sshd**. The next command from this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/130482/how-to-check-sshd-log) was of help:

```
tail -n 500 /var/log/auth.log | grep 'sshd'
```

In my case I accidentally changed the home directory and subdirectory ownership and modes but once inside the VM, the following commands didn' work:

```
sudo chmod -R 700 /home/vagrant/.ssh
sudo chmod 600 /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chown -R vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.ssh
```

I tried to generate a new keypair in the Host (the ssh client) following this [link](https://computingforgeeks.com/fix-vagrant-ssh-authentication-failure-after-packaging-vagrant-box/) and copy (using a python web server as explained at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801718/how-to-run-a-http-server-which-serves-a-specific-path) by Jerzy Pawlikowski) the public key into the guest VM (the ssh server) but it was not successful either.
In the end I had to destroy the VM which is not a real solution in my own opinion:

```
vagrant destroy
```

Then I launched again the new machine:

```
vagrant up
```

At the startup, I noticed the following log:

```
default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
default:
default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
```

Instead of destroying the VM, my proposed solution therefore is to give correct ownership and modes to the ssh directory in the VM and also delete all keys (both in VM and Host) so that Vagrant can only checkout the **insecure key** and generate a new keypair by itself. See also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471542/cant-ssh-to-vagrant-vms-using-the-insecure-private-key-vagrant-1-7-2) about **config.ssh.insert_key**, this other [link](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/9831) explaining a similar procedure by JuPlutonic and this last [link](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/5186) by mtchavez.

Answer (score 0):

I have started the machine, then:

```
vagrant ssh-config
```

I've gotten the following:

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/my-user-name/Documents/PHP-Projects/my-php-project/puphpet/files/dot/ssh/id_rsa
  IdentityFile /Users/my-user-name/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

Then I've ran

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa > /Users/my-user-name/Documents/PHP-Projects/my-php-project/puphpet/files/dot/ssh/id_rsa
```

Machine booted from here on

- El Capitan 10.11.1 Beta (15B38b)
- Virtual Box 5.0.8 r103449
- Vagrant 1.7.4

Answer (score 0):

Between all of the responses here, there are lots of good things to try. For completeness, if you

`ssh vagrant@localhost -p 2222`

as @Bizmate suggests, and it fails, be sure you have

`AllowUsers vagrant`

in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` of your guest/vagrant machine.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Vagrant with a Puphpet setup from May 2015 and had this problem. It appears that the configuration that was generated didn't handle Vagrant 1.7.4 (or maybe a bit earlier?) behavior of regenerating ssh keys if it detects an insecure key.

I solved it by adding the following in my Puphpet generated Vagrantfile (local setup) inside the "if File.file?(customKey)" clause:

```
config.ssh.insert_key = false
```

[Reference commit](https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/commit/bf324b618ee43596f099925fee4c585d6f6a493f)

Answer (score 0):

This the all correct steps that I followed for fix this bellow issue occurred when vagrant up command run.

These are the steps that I followed

1. create a folder. e.g F:\projects
2. Open this folder in git bash and run this command 
      ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com" (put a valid email address)
3. Then generating key pair in two separate files in the project folder. e.g  project(private key file), project.pub (public key file)
4. Go to this location C:\Users\acer.vagrant.d and find file
   insecure_private_key
5. Get backup of the file and copy the content of newly created private key and paste it in insecure_private_key file. Then copy insecure_private_key and paste it in this location too.
6. Now vagrant up in your project location. after generating above issue type vagrant ssh and go inside giving username, password. (in default username and password is set as vagrant)
7. Go inside to this location  cd /home/vagrant/.ssh and type mv authorized_keys authorized_keys_bk
8. Then type ls -al and type vi authorized_keys for open authorized_keys file vi editor.
9. Open generated public key from notepad++ (project.pub) and copy content
   Then press i on git bash to enable insert mode on vi editor and right click and paste. After press escape to get out from insert mode
10. :wq! for save the file and type ls -al
11. Then permissions are set like bellow no need to change
      drwx------. 2 vagrant vagrant 4096 Feb 13 15:33 .
    drwx------. 4 vagrant vagrant 4096 Feb 13 14:04 ..
    -rw-------. 1 vagrant vagrant  743 Feb 13 14:26 authorized_keys
    -rw-------. 1 root    root     409 Feb 13 13:57 authorized_keys_bk
    -rw-------. 1 vagrant vagrant  409 Jan  2 23:09 authorized_keys_originial
    Otherwise type chmod 600 authorized_keys and type this command too chown vagrant:vagrant authorized_keys
12. Finally run the vagrant halt and vagrant up again.

************************THIS IS WORK FINE FOR ME*******************************

Answer (score 0):

Just for those people that have been idiots like me, or have had something odd happen to their vagrant machine. This error can also occur when you changed the permissions of the vagrant user's home directory (deliberately or by accident).

You can log in instead (as described in other posts) using the password ('vagrant') and then run the following command to fix the permissions.

`sudo chown -R vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant`

Then you should be able to log in again without entering the password.

**TL;DR: The permissions on your vagrant home folder are wrong.**

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
homestead destroy
homestead up
```

Edit (Not as simple as first thought):

The issue was that new versions of homestead use `php7.0` and some other stuff. To avoid this mess up make sure you set the `verison` in `Homestead.yml`:

```
version: "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by running commands on windows 7 CMD as given in this here is the link last post on this thread,

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6744

```
Some commands that will reinitialize various network states:
Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults : netsh winsock reset catalog
Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults : netsh int ip reset reset.log
Flush DNS resolver cache : ipconfig /flushdns
Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases : ipconfig /registerdns
Flush routing table : route /f
```

Answer (score 0):

Been beating my head on this for the last couple of days on a repackaged base box. (Mac OS X, El Capitan)

Following @Radek 's procedure I did 'vagrant ssh-config' on the source box and got:

```
...
/Users/Shared/dev/<source-box-name>/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
...
```

On the new copy, that command gave me:

```
...
IdentityFile /Users/<username>/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
...
```

So, I just added this line in the new copy:

```
...
config.ssh.private_key_path = "/Users/Shared/dev/<source-box-name>/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key"
...
```

Not perfect, but I can get on with my life.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your case is the same as mine though.
In my case `vagrant ssh` failed in key authentication and asked for password.
I found my old setting below in my `~/.ssh/config` (at the top of the file).

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
```

After removing this, key authentication started working. No more password asked.

Answer (score 0):

Facing this problem nowdays using Windows 10, Vagrant 2.2.6 and VM VBox 5.2
Tried almost all previous saying to rewrite or point to the ssh public key from the host, but none of this worked for me. The only solution actually did the trick was the one from @Mohit Verma, copying this 3 lines:

```
config.ssh.username = 'vagrant'
config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'
config.ssh.insert_key = 'true'
```

into the vagrantfile, after the `config.vm.provision` block.
then ran the `vagrant up` command and it worked! some interresting messages on the console stating that it was replacing the public and private keys on its own after doing this change. Hope this helps, all credit to Mohit Verma posting his solution on 2021