# CoreOS Vagrant Virtual box SSH password

Tags: linux, ssh, vagrant, putty, coreos

I'm trying to SSH into [CoreOS Virtual Box](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-vagrant) using Putty. I know the username appears in the output when I do Vagrant up but I don't know what the password is.

I've also tried overriding it with `config.ssh.password` settings in Vagrantfile but when I do `vagrant up` again it comes up with Authentication failure warning and retries endlessly.

How do we use Putty to log into this Box instance?

Comment: do you have any solution?, I have same problem using CoreOS with Vagrant.

Answer (score 3):

By default there is no password set for the core user, only key-based authentication. If you'd like to set a password this can be done [via cloud-config](https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/setup/cloudinit-cloud-config/#users).

Place the cloud-config file in a user-data file within the cloned repository. View user-data.sample for an example.

A better method would be to follow [this guide](http://eamann.com/tech/vagrant-windows/) so that you can use `vagrant ssh` as it was designed.

Comment: The default password for the user 'vagrant' was 'vagrant' for me.  I recommend trying that before assuming that there is no password.  Root may not have a password though.

Answer (score 2):

By default for **Vagrant**:

user: *vagrant*

password: *vagrant*

> ..vagrant up again it comes up with Authentication failure warning and
>   retries endlessly.

I think because it make connect with wrong *ssh public key*.
To change it read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23554973/3563993