# Unable to login to vagrant with vagrant up after setting up ssh keys

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ssh-keys, vagrantfile

I have a new user in my vagrant box(trusty64) and I am trying to ssh into it. Instead of logging into `vagrant` user after `vagrant up`, I want to login to my username.

*What I have done so far*

1. Created a user in my guest machine.
2. Created ssh key in my host using `ssh-keygen`
3. Copied the ssh key to the guest using `ssh-copy-id -p 2222 -i shash@127.0.0.1`

*and the part of the Vagrantfile looks like this*

```
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.ssh.username = "shash"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

I can use `ssh -p '2222' 'shash@127.0.0.1'` to login directly but when I give `vagrant up` I keep getting the following error

```
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

Any help in sorting out this is really appreciated.Thanks!

A complete set-up guide would be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

The vagrant file will access that users home directory when you specify '~'.

config.ssh.private_key_path = "/home/shash/.ssh/authorized_keys"

Give that a go!

Comment: I tried it. It just does not work. :( Any other options that I can try?

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
end
```

1. config.ssh.private_key_path is your local private key
2. Your private key must be available to the local ssh-agent. You can check with ssh-add -L, if it's not listed add it with ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
3. Don't forget to add you public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the Vagrant VM. You can do it copy-and-pasting or using a tool like ssh-copy-id

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23554973/3563993