# Why does vagrant throw authentication errors when running the up command?

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I have just got onto my machine and added a new site to my vagrant setup file in the Homestead.yaml file like so:

```
    ---
    ip: "192.168.10.10"
    memory: 2048
    cpus: 1
    provider: virtualbox

    authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

    keys:
        - ~/.ssh/id_rsa


   folders:
    - map: /Freelance/projects
      to: /home/vagrant/projects
    - map: /Freelance/projects/synergy-camps/synergy-camps
      to: /home/vagrant/projects

sites:
    - map: scoff_app.local
      to: /home/vagrant/projects/scoff/scoff-api/public
    - map: phpmyadmin.app
      to: /home/vagrant/projects/phpmyadmin
    - map: synergy_camps.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/projects/synergy-camps/synergy-camps/public

databases:
    - homestead
    - synergycamps

    databases:
        - homestead
        - synergycamps

    variables:
        - key: APP_ENV
          value: local

    # blackfire:
    #     - id: foo
    #       token: bar
    #       client-id: foo
    #       client-token: bar

    # ports:
    #     - send: 93000
    #       to: 9300
    #     - send: 7777
```

When I cd into my /Homestead directory and run:

`vagrant up`

I get the error below:

```
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

Has anyone had this before?

Comment: have you initiated the vagrant homestead in you new directory...?

Comment: how is that done @hhsadiq?

Comment: Is your VM still booting or after that warning it goes down?

Comment: yeah it boots but then I get the error once it starts to authenticate,i have tried removing insecure_private_key and tried inserting my own but I still get the sameerror

Comment: Ok. I have deleted my answer as it was not valid. You should answer your question, the way you solved this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your key is correct?

It could be possible that your VM is asking a question while booting the machine.

For more options to fix this, see the following answers:
[Vagrant ssh authentication failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922891/vagrant-ssh-authentication-failure)