# Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying

Tags: centos, vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrantfile

## I tried

to spin up a CentOS 7 VM. Below is my settings

**Vagrant File**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.define "zabbix1" do |zabbix1|
    zabbix1.vm.box = "centos/7"
    zabbix1.vm.hostname = "zabbix1"
    zabbix1.ssh.insert_key = false
    zabbix1.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.11.12.55"
    zabbix1.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
    zabbix1.ssh.forward_agent = true
  end


end
```

---

## Result

**vagrant reload**

```
==> zabbix1: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
    zabbix1: Guest communication could not be established! This is usually because
    zabbix1: SSH is not running, the authentication information was changed,
    zabbix1: or some other networking issue. Vagrant will force halt, if
    zabbix1: capable.
==> zabbix1: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> zabbix1: Checking if box 'centos/7' is up to date...
==> zabbix1: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> zabbix1: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2204.
==> zabbix1: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> zabbix1: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    zabbix1: Adapter 1: nat
    zabbix1: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> zabbix1: Forwarding ports...
    zabbix1: 22 (guest) => 2204 (host) (adapter 1)
==> zabbix1: Booting VM...
==> zabbix1: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    zabbix1: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2204
    zabbix1: SSH username: vagrant
    zabbix1: SSH auth method: private key
    zabbix1: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    zabbix1: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    zabbix1: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    zabbix1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    zabbix1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    zabbix1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    zabbix1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    zabbix1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    zabbix1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

**vagrant ssh-config**

```
Host zabbix1
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2204
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/bheng/.ssh/id_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
  ForwardAgent yes
```

---

What did I do wrong ? What did I miss ?

Comment: Try this solution [Vagrant ssh authentication failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922891/vagrant-ssh-authentication-failure?rq=1).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with the same box and the way I fixed it was to log into the VM from VirtualBox (vagrant/vagrant as username/password) and change the permission of `.ssh/authorized_keys`

```
chmod 0600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Do that after you run `vagrant up` (while the error repeats) and the VM is up and you will see `vagrant up` will complete successfully and you will be able to ssh into the VM from `vagrant ssh`

Answer (score 0):

Private networks can be configured manually or with the VirtualBox built-in DHCP server. This works for me.

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.define "zabbix1" do |zabbix1|
       zabbix1.vm.box = "centos/7"
       zabbix1.vm.hostname = "zabbix1"
       zabbix1.ssh.insert_key = false
       zabbix1.vm.network :private_network, type: "dhcp"
   end
end
```

Next you have to use **vagrant destory** and **vagrant up**.

Comment: I updated my post and added the result of my `vagrant ssh-config`

Comment: Have you only one defined machine "zabbix"  in Vagrantfile ?

Comment: I can show you my entire Vagrant file, if you want. :)

Comment: Done. I updated my post, and include my entire Vagrant file. :)