# Laravel Homestead vagrant up times out

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, ssh, vagrant, homestead

I'm following the official guide for running Laravel 5.1 on Homestead.

But when I try `vagrant up` it hangs up at `homestead-7: SSH auth method: private key` and eventually times out with the message:

```
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

My SSH keys were generated using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "you@homestead"`.

Can't access the machine through `vagrant ssh`, it outputs `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`.

Tried `vagrant destroy` and deleting the `~/.homestead` folder to start again from scratch but same result.

Using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit, Vagrant 1.8.4 and VirtualBox 5.0.18. Virtualization is enabled in my computer, other boxes boot up without problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vagrant ssh authentication failure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23554973/4133798)

Comment: Tried all approaches mentioned in that answer, same result. Also tried accessing through SSH but I get `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Running Win 10 Pro v 1607, VirtualBox 5.0.30, Vagrant 1.9.1 and Homestead 1.0.1.

I had same issues as described. Vagrant up command would run cleanly but hang at the `SSH username: private key` message.
Reinstalled, checked .yaml file, recreated ssh keys - tried all the usual stuff without success.

Finally working when I changed the network setting in my Virtual Box.

1. Brought up VirtualBox program with windows UI
2. Clicked on Network - in the 'Adapter 1' tab, then opened up Advanced
3. Clicked 'Cable Connected' checkbox
4. At console $ prompt, `vagrant halt`
5. then `vagrant up`

All then worked as expected. Unticked 'cable connected' and again vagrant up hanged. Reset 'cable connected' and vagrant up running correctly again.

The default settings for importing the base Laravel/Homestead box leaves the 'cable connected' setting unchecked/off

See [vagrant issue 7648 for some background](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7648)

If you don't want to keep ticking the cable connected box, the permanent fix is:

Locating the `Vagrantfile` file in the `Homestead` folder (probably its file path is `~/Homestead/Vagrantfile`), and adding following to the `Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|` block fixes issue:

```
config.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |vb|
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--cableconnected1', 'on']
end
```

With this change to the Vagrantfile `vagrant up` works on new imported laravel/homestead box

Comment: Hmm is this still valid @HamptonNorth, cause when i put it inside i get an error when i tried to destroy with homestead destroy

Line number: 16
Message: NoMethodError: undefined method `config' for File:Class

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Windows, you may need to enable hardware virtualization (VT-x). It can usually be enabled via your BIOS. If you are using **Hyper-V** on a UEFI system you may additionally need to disable Hyper-V in order to access VT-x.

I had virtualization turned on, but in VirtualBox it showed that no, I turned off Hyper-V and it all worked.

[image]

Comment: This is for you guys, who where messing up with Hyper-V, Windows feature for installing virtual OSes like Ubuntu, etc. That was my exact case.

Answer (score 4):

I sometimes hang on `vagrant up` with the error `SSH username: private key`

try

`vagrant halt`
`vagrant up`

Comment: actually i just ran into this problem again, `vagrant reload` did not work, had to find my original answer to get it back up

Answer (score 2):

If it times out on ssh-key authentication it seems to be a host/guest communication error.

To confirm try `ssh vagrant@192.168.10.10`

If it throws an error or times-out again make sure the virtual machine is shut down completely, by running vagrant halt and using the Virtualbox GUI to confirm this.

Under network I sure my adapter was "Cable Connected" and for my host only adapter I set "allow all" for promiscuis mode.

[image: Virtual box Network settings screen]

[!Virtual box Network settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8t1z.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8t1z.png)

I then ran `vagrant up --provision`
 and there was no wait during the authentication between the two.

After the vagrant provisioner script has run you may now `vagrant ssh` in

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this problem and tried editing it in the VirtualBox Gui but my Homestead machine didn't appear in the list, here's the solution if it doesn't :

```
VBoxManage list runningvms
```

find your homestead machine in the list, it'll mostly be labelled "Homestead-x" (For me it was "Homestead-7")
then run the following commands :

```
VBoxManage startvm "homestead-7" --type emergencystop
VBoxManage modifyvm "homestead-7" --cableconnected1 on
```

Afterwards cd into your homestead folder and you'll notice the machine was aborted, a simple `vagrant up` will start your machine successfully and without stop.
Also consider adding the bit of code provided by @HamptonNorth to your VagrantFile for a permanent fix.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it worked by **deleting ".vagrant" folder** located next to Vagrantfile.

Scenario were following:

1. I was working with this box previously
2. Reinstalled my PC. Before that I exported box package file so its ready for setup next time.
3. Imported `package.box` after fresh Windows 10 installation
4. `vagrant up` , and then got stuck similar as described in question.

Looks like there are some kind of conflict if there are existing ".vagrant" folder, probably ssh keys or something.

Comment: Deleting the .vagrant folder inside the Homestead folder worked for me. Homestead rebuilt everything, and it fixed other problems I was having at the same time. Thanks :)