# Can't provision authorized_keys file into VM using Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, ssh-keys, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows, vagrant-provision

I am trying to use my own pair of RSA SSH-2 keys with Vagrant 1.9.5 on VirtualBox 5.1.22 with Windows 7 SP1 host and a CentOS 7.3 guest.

When I execute `vagrant up` I get :

```
Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
SSH username: vagrant
SSH auth method: private key
Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
...
```

I have found that the cause is failing to connect to the guest because the required key is not being added to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys but it contains Vagrant's default `insecure_private_key`.

This is my Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.boot_timeout = 120
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.ssh.private_key_path = ["vagrant-setup/keys/my_openssh.key"]
  # This is not copying authorized_keys to the guest
  config.vm.provision "file", source: "vagrant-setup/.ssh/authorized_keys", destination: "~/.ssh/autorized_keys"
  # Setting forward_agent to true and adding the key to Pageant doesn't make any difference
  config.ssh.forward_agent = false

  config.vm.define "MyMachineName" do |vs|

    vs.vm.box = "vagrant-centos-73-x86_64-puppet"
    vs.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/CommanderK5/packer-centos-template/releases/download/0.7.3/vagrant-centos-7.3.box"

    # The shell script that will execute once just after the VM is created
    vs.vm.provision "shell", path: "vagrant-setup/setup.sh"

    # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine using a specific IP.
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.101.110"

    vs.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      # Enable the GUI of VirtualBox and see whether the VM is waiting for input on startup
      vb.gui = false
    end
  end

end
```

I have tried copying autorized_keys using `vm.provision "shell"` and `cp` from the guest. I have tried to change the permissions of autorized_keys on the guest before copying but nothing seems to work because it does not connect. And I have tried to perform the copy inside MyMachineName like `vs.vm.provision "file", ...`

If I login in once using `vagrant ssh` with user+password and I write authorized_keys by hand then afterwards I am able to log in with the SSH key and no password.

`vagrant ssh-config` reports

```
Host MyMachineName
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile C:/MyMachineName/vagrant-setup/keys/my_openssh.key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

Putting the private key into `C:\Users\My User Name\.ssh\id_rsa` seems to make some difference, like if Vagrant was still looking for something there despite I explicitly set my own private key, but does not make it work. And it also seems to have a problem with `C:\Users\My User Name\` having spaces but since it should not be used then that should not matter.

So the question is **How do I make Vagrant work with my own pair of SSH keys without having to tweak the guest VM by hand?**

There are plenty of replies at this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922891/vagrant-ssh-authentication-failure/23554973#23554973), but most of them come down to put the key in authorized_keys by hand, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: In case it matters, this is my test authorized_keys `ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAvUzbdG0Ex2fr31DPVt6FKAEP+iqpuuJFyxI0962VmaP+UTP23X9YWOsovDbb6izUru0FmjRbfiLhv8GZZ+fUXC0B/xorR/Bm7Ku2ruZ1x1Fuc59NRmqf9AAwm1zV1C3kCPM5LVMOUVChvX3dqgEf7vSbtcmQRECGS2dDbF6cdVMdMg2m1Zn3E34B6y3cB7Csko3fUW9dbyhZPpcx//vGYrNVTzIOOT8EAzvnJeYpNeIhRk1Qk4i9cxPVjqVvnyaIfUJyGRdr/+rYQkp2i+hOAR7xqzTKnzuDWiIV2RTHD6ImZNfkWDC0wgMSFLdRe4ch/p+eJxhyJZZkteMPJ9QlWQ== CentOrion RSA 2048 SSH-2 login key`

Comment: Can you connect using simple `ssh`? Isn't there a firewall running on that server?

Comment: No firewall. I am building on my own standalone laptop and even Windows firewall is totally disabled. If I force ssh connect to the guest with user+password using `vagrant ssh -- -vvv` and I add the text on my previous comment to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys then I can use my private key afterwards. The problem is that when bringing the VM up, Vagrant seems to ignore my private key and always puts its own insecure_private_key at guest's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys so when during `vagrant up` it tries to login to provision it fails and enters the retry loop.

Comment: not super nice, but https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8058#issuecomment-266193873 should help to work this with a provisioning script

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Frédéric Henri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4296747/fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric-henri) comment, this is what worked for me in order to login only with my own key and not insecure key nor user+password :

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  rsakey = File.read("vagrant-setup/keys/authorized_keys")
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-EOC
    echo '#{rsakey}' >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
    sed --in-place=.bak -r 's/^#?(PermitRootLogin|PermitEmptyPasswords|PasswordAuthentication|X11Forwarding) yes/\1 no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    sed --in-place=.bak '/== vagrant insecure public key$/d' /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
  EOC

  config.vm.define "MyMachine" do |vs|
    vs.vm.box = "vagrant-centos-73-x86_64-puppet"
    vs.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/CommanderK5/packer-centos-template/releases/download/0.7.3/vagrant-centos-7.3.box"

    # SSH settings
    vs.ssh.private_key_path = ['~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key', "vagrant-setup/keys/my_openssh.key"]

    # The shell script that will execute once just after the VM is created
    vs.vm.provision "shell", path: "vagrant-setup/my_own_custom_setup_stuff.sh"

    # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine using a specific IP.
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.101.110"
  end

end
```