# Vagrant connection failures on AWS Ubuntu 16

Tags: vagrant, nomad

## My problem

I'm fairly new to Vagrant, so apologies if this question is rudimentary.

I am trying to inspect Nomad, which in turn [requires Vagrant to run](https://www.nomadproject.io/intro/getting-started/install.html). I have spawned a new Ubuntu 16 machine on EC2, installed virtualbox and Vagrant, and entered `vagrant up` as instructed:

```
$ vagrant up
VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` to see the error message which should contain
instructions on how to fix this error.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-26-135:~/vagrant_config$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04'
    default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/bento/ubuntu-16.04
==> default: Adding box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' (v2.3.8) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/bento/boxes/ubuntu-16.04/versions/2.3.8/providers/virtualbox.box
==> default: Successfully added box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' (v2.3.8) for 'virtualbox'!
==> default: Importing base box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: vagrant_config_default_1502307080428_76965
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key

Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.
```

## What have I tried

- Rebooting the AWS VM
- Checking for disk full / High memory / High CPU usage (found nothing)
- Removing the vagrant box and re-installing it
- Re-provisioning

## My question

How to handle ssh timeout with Vagrant on an Ubuntu 16 EC2 Machine?

Comment: Have you checked the VirtualBox error?

Comment: Hi adam-matan, your question seems related to `SSH auth method: private key`. I tried to use the vagrant-file provided by nomad, and did `vagrant up` in my local ubuntu machine (I dont have ec2 acc). I am able to make my vagrant running. could ssh it too.  I found similar issue in [different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922891/vagrant-ssh-authentication-failure). To `Remove the vagrant box` you should try from same folder where your vagrant up done, execute `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant box remove bento/ubuntu-16.04` which cleans properly. try follow the link.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of unrelated, but Nomad does not require Vagrant.  You can run nomad on any machine, just download the binary(https://www.nomadproject.io/downloads.html) and run it.