# Laravel Homestead warning: Vagrant authentication failure

Tags: laravel, virtualbox, homestead, ubuntu-18.04, vagrantfile

Authentication failure came up while I'm trying to deploy Laravel project to Homestead environment. Error message and some other attempts are demonstrated in the screenshot below:

[image]

**Environment**

- Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
- Latest version of **VirtualBox**
- Latest version of **Homestead**
- latest version of **Vagrant**

**Vagrantfile**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION ||= "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = confDir + "/Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
customizationScriptPath = confDir + "/user-customizations.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.require_version '>= 2.1.0'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exist? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "/tmp/bash_aliases"
        config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
            s.inline = "awk '{ sub(\"\r$\", \"\"); print }' /tmp/bash_aliases > /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases && chown vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases"
        end
    end

    if File.exist? homesteadYamlPath then
        settings = YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath))
    elsif File.exist? homesteadJsonPath then
        settings = JSON::parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath))
    else
        abort "Homestead settings file not found in #{confDir}"
    end

    Homestead.configure(config, settings)

    if File.exist? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath, privileged: false, keep_color: true
    end

    if File.exist? customizationScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: customizationScriptPath, privileged: false, keep_color: true
    end

    if Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-hostsupdater')
        config.hostsupdater.aliases = settings['sites'].map { |site| site['map'] }
    elsif Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-hostmanager')
        config.hostmanager.enabled = true
        config.hostmanager.manage_host = true
        config.hostmanager.aliases = settings['sites'].map { |site| site['map'] }
    end
end
```

**Homestead.yaml file**

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/laravel_one
      to: /home/vagrant/laravel_one

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/laravel_one/public

databases:
    - homestead

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# zray:
#  If you've already freely registered Z-Ray, you can place the token here.
#     - email: foo@bar.com
#       token: foo
#  Don't forget to ensure that you have 'zray: "true"' for your site.
```

**My solutions:**

- I followed the instructions of [Homestead environment installation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead)
- Solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922891/vagrant-ssh-authentication-failure) is not helping. I have tried [Solution 01](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23554973/2828685), [Solution 02](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38760351/2828685), [Solution 03](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32106919/2828685), [Solution 04](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30792296/2828685)

I assume there're some bugs in **Ubuntu + Homestead + Vagrant + VirtualBox** environment.

Any other idea to figure this out?

Comment: I simply restarted the computer and it's fixed. Maybe the IP address are reallocated after the reboot.