# Vagrant box: default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying

Tags: laravel-4, connection, localhost, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm having trouble getting vagrant box running. I tried the solution in this thread: [Vagrant stuck connection timeout retrying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575261/vagrant-stuck-connection-timeout-retrying). No luck there. I also tried increasing the value of config.vm.boot_timeout. No luck either. Please help!

```
$ vagrant destroy && vagrant up
    default: Are you sure you want to destroy the 'default' VM? [y/N] y
==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: Homestead_default_1404542131789_93737
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 9000 (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 => 33060 (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 => 54320 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575261/vagrant-stuck-connection-timeout-retrying in this question, the seccond answer works for me.

Comment: The situation could be because of VirtualBox failed to redirect ports, despite saying 
'**==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)**'
You may have a look at full description in my question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529651/virtualbox-nat-failed-to-redirect-tcp-127-0-0-12222-10-0-2-1522).
I still have no idea how to fix redirection fail(
Please drop a note in my post, if and how you succeed!

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable Virtual Machine option in your BIOS to make VirtualBox work as expected.

For virtualisation settings : http://www.sysprobs.com/disable-enable-virtualization-technology-bios

Answer (score 0):

The messages you have posted here are printed pretty much at the end of the VM startup.

So, as I see it, there are two main reasons for this

1. You have a firewall, so you can't access vagrant machine even from you localhost. I would try to disable the firewall and run again.
2. Your guest machine is just to heavy, a lot of things happen on startup, before it gets actually available so vagrant gets a timeout. In this case update the value of **config.vm.boot_timeout** in vm's configuration file as vagrant kindly states.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Enable gui input of keyboard in your vagrant configuration file

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.gui = true
end
```