# vagrant: how to add GUI to vagrant by modifying Vagrantfile?

Tags: laravel-4, virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I need to see the GUI when I do "vagrant up --provision" because I believe the box was shutdown improperly and now simply time-outs when I try to start it.  I see from the [documentation] that I can add a block to my Vagrantfile to enable me to debug the startup process.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575261/vagrant-stuck-connection-timeout-retrying) says if the system was shutdown improperly it will ask me if I want to boot up in safe mode (only visible from the GUI).  So I am trying to modify the Vagrantfile and have tried two ways (I'm not very familiar with Ruby or modifying config files).  When I try this:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

path = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}"

require 'yaml'
require path + '/scripts/homestead.rb'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
   Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(path + '/Homestead.yaml')))

config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  vb.gui = true
end

end
```

I get the following error message:

```
Path: <provider config: virtualbox>
Message: undefined local variable or method `vb' for main:Object
```

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?  How do I modify the file properly so that I can get the vagrant box up and running again.  I am trying to use Homestead for Laravel, by the way.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you try changing `vb.gui = true` to `v.gui = true` ?

(`vb` doesn't seem to be something available in your namespace)

Comment: @Sankalp thanks, you're right, i changed the "|v|" to "|vb|" and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: You kinda did the opposite (replace `v` with `vb`) of what I suggested... but yeah, that works too :)