# Vagrant: Remote Connection Disconnect in OS X Yosemite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, virtualbox, osx-yosemite

I planned to test a Ruby on Rails project using vagrant in this box: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/nickcharlton/boxes/ruby-box.

The goal is to view the application in the host's browser.

Firstly, I have updated my virtualbox to 4.3.26 and my vagrant.

By following http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/basic_usage.html, I tried 
`config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000`
and
`config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10`.
Actually, I can ping "192.168.33.10" from the host's terminal. But in the browser, I cannot reach the guest from localhost:3000 or 127.0.0.1:3000 or 192.168.33.10 or other url combinations.

The rails application should be working fine inside the guest because nothing went wrong from the `bundle install` process to `rails s`.

I can always boot the virtual machine and log in through ssh, however, I cannot get access to the application in either Firefox or Safari. That is when I noticed the endless `Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...`

Honestly I do not understand why after some repeated messages there would come `==> default: Machine booted and ready!` and vagrant ssh would work just fine even in this situation.

I have tried a lot of ways to solve this problem.

1. [Vagrant stuck connection timeout retrying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575261/vagrant-stuck-connection-timeout-retrying)

I've tried adding "vb.gui = true" in VagrantFile, but it did not work out.

2. http://laravel.io/forum/05-27-2014-laravel-homestead-not-connecting-when-wifi-is-enabled

I've tried changing my DNS, and I've tried disconnecting my wifi, but they did not work out.

The Vagrantfile is like the following:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "nickcharlton/ruby-box"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
   config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
     vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
   end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   sudo apt-get update
  #   sudo apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved?