# VM: * Network type 'public_netwrok' is invalid. Please use a valid network type

Tags: networking, vagrant, virtual-machine

Can anyone explain why I am getting the following error

```
VM: Network type 'public_netwrok' is invalid. Please use a valid network type.
```

when I try to bring vagrant up on Virtual Box with the following Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |o|
o.vm.box = "precise32"
o.vm.box_url = "http://aka.ms/vagrant-win7-ie10"
o.vm.synced_folder "./app","/var/www/", create:true
o.vm.network :public_netwrok, ip: "172.27.55.3"
o.vm.provision :shell, :path => "setup.sh"
end
```

All possible scenarios related to network type has been tried without any luck since last week and I am fully stuck now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo. Replace:

`o.vm.network :public_netwrok, ip: "172.27.55.3"`

with:

`o.vm.network "public_network", ip: "172.27.55.3"`

Comment: Thanks it solves the mentioned issue.    Another issue occurred is about  default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
 default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...:

Comment: It could be a few things. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575261/vagrant-stuck-connection-timeout-retrying

Comment: Thanks buddy , I still need further help .                                            vagrantfile is as follows:                                             Vagrant.configure("2") do |o|
     o.vm.box = "precise32"
     o.vm.box_url = "http://aka.ms/vagrant-win7-ie10"
     o.vm.synced_folder "./app","/var/www/", create:true
     o.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
end