# launching vagrant always connection timeout

Tags: vagrant, laravel-5.1, homestead

I am having problem everytime I issue this command "vagrant up"
I have this error see image below.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vagrant stuck connection timeout retrying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575261/vagrant-stuck-connection-timeout-retrying)

Comment: you might want to check this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472304/why-am-i-unable-to-connect-to-ubuntu-wily64-vagrant-box/32472748#32472748) too