# Solution for vagrant installation

Tags: vagrant, cakephp-3.0

i need your help because i have to use cakebox for a project but i have some problems when i type vagrant up i get this error. I tried everything but it did not work.

Thanks in advance !

```
My-PC MINGW64 /A/App_LeagueUp!/cakebox (dev)

$ vagrant up

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...

==> default: Importing base box 'cakebox'...

==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...

==> default: Setting the name of the VM: cakebox_default_1444639086577_31058

==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...

==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...

    default: Adapter 1: nat

    default: Adapter 2: hostonly

==> default: Forwarding ports...

    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)

==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...

==> default: Booting VM...

==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...

    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222

    default: SSH username: vagrant

    default: SSH auth method: private key

    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Comment: `I tried everything` , can you detail ? so we dont repeat what you know

Comment: you can check http://stackoverflow.com/a/23095019/4296747

Answer (score 0):

My recomendation to figure out the problem is to set the

vb.gui flag to true in your Vagrantfile . add run then vagrant up. this will open the console, on a different window. It sometimes happen to me and then i reboot and everything is working fine.

If it doesnt post findings here, at least youll have more info

Comment: I tried what you suggested to me but i get the same errors

Comment: What do you see in the console window(not where you did, vagrant up the VirtualBox one [if using virtualbox]), do you see any errors?

Comment: There is nothing that appears

Comment: Whats nothing? :P You see the virtualbox splash screen, then the boot process starts and then.... you see the login? what do u see?

Comment: I don't have the login, ii just offers me the choice between Ubuntu and Advenced options for ubuntu, and when I chose one of this options the console window appears empty without any errors and i can't write on

Comment: have you updated the ubuntu? sudo apt-get upgrade or dist-upgrade, anyway the way to fix that would be to go to advanced-options, and fix the actual vm. I dont think vagrant has anything to do at this point

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable virtualization from your boot menu and try it again.