# Can't initialize VM using vagrant

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I can't initialize vagrant typing `vagrant up` on cmd (Windows 10), this is the logs

`

```
C:\xampp\apache\ecomex\ecomex>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'ecomex' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> ecomex: Loading Berkshelf datafile...
==> ecomex: Sharing cookbooks with VM
==> ecomex: Checking if box 'grtjn/centos-7.0' is up to date...
==> ecomex: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> ecomex: Updating Vagrant's Berkshelf...
==> ecomex: Resolving cookbook dependencies...
==> ecomex: Fetching 'ecomex' from source at cookbooks/ecomex
==> ecomex: Using apt (3.0.0)
==> ecomex: Using ark (1.0.1)
==> ecomex: Using build-essential (3.2.0)
==> ecomex: Using chef_handler (1.3.0)
==> ecomex: Using ecomex (0.0.1) from source at cookbooks/ecomex
==> ecomex: Using nodejs (2.2.0)
==> ecomex: Using redisio (2.3.0)
==> ecomex: Using seven_zip (2.0.0)
==> ecomex: Using ulimit (0.3.3)
==> ecomex: Using windows (1.39.2)
==> ecomex: Using yum (3.10.0)
==> ecomex: Using yum-epel (0.6.6)
==> ecomex: Vendoring apt (3.0.0) to C:/Users/EruAizen/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20160329-4476-mlo9s9-ecomex/apt
==> ecomex: Vendoring ark (1.0.1) to C:/Users/EruAizen/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20160329-4476-mlo9s9-ecomex/ark
==> ecomex: Vendoring build-essential (3.2.0) to C:/Users/EruAizen/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20160329-4476-mlo9s9-ecomex/build-essential
==> ecomex: Vendoring chef_handler (1.3.0) to C:/Users/EruAizen/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20160329-4476-mlo9s9-ecomex/chef_handler
==> ecomex: Vendoring ecomex (0.0.1) to C:/Users/EruAizen/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20160329-4476-mlo9s9-ecomex/ecomex
==> ecomex: Vendoring nodejs (2.2.0) to C:/Users/EruAizen/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20160329-4476-mlo9s9-ecomex/nodejs
==> ecomex: Vendoring redisio (2.3.0) to C:/Users/EruAizen/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20160329-4476-mlo9s9-ecomex/redisio
==> ecomex: Vendoring seven_zip (2.0.0) to C:/Users/EruAizen/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20160329-4476-mlo9s9-ecomex/seven_zip
==> ecomex: Vendoring ulimit (0.3.3) to C:/Users/EruAizen/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20160329-4476-mlo9s9-ecomex/ulimit
==> ecomex: Vendoring windows (1.39.2) to C:/Users/EruAizen/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20160329-4476-mlo9s9-ecomex/windows
==> ecomex: Vendoring yum (3.10.0) to C:/Users/EruAizen/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20160329-4476-mlo9s9-ecomex/yum
==> ecomex: Vendoring yum-epel (0.6.6) to C:/Users/EruAizen/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20160329-4476-mlo9s9-ecomex/yum-epel
==> ecomex: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> ecomex: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    ecomex: Adapter 1: nat
==> ecomex: Forwarding ports...
    ecomex: 3000 (guest) => 9898 (host) (adapter 1)
==> ecomex: Booting VM...
==> ecomex: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    ecomex: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:22
    ecomex: SSH username: vagrant
    ecomex: SSH auth method: private key
```

`

afther a few minutes, it trows the next error message

> Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
>   Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
>   the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.
>
> If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
>   Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
>   are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.
>
> If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
>   working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
>   problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
>   Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
>   as well.
>
> If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
>   the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.

my vagrant file

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby
VM = 'ecomex'

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  #selecting Cent OS 7.0
  config.vm.box = 'grtjn/centos-7.0'
  config.vbguest.auto_update = false
  # proxy network: Node: 3000 & Apache: 9898
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host:9898, auto_correct: true
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 2222, id: "ssh", disabled: "true"

  #VirtualBox setup
  config.vm.define VM
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.name = VM
  end

  #Fixing issue: stdin is not tty
  ssh_fix = 'bash -c "BASH_ENV=/etc/profile exec bash"'
  config.ssh.shell = ssh_fix unless ARGV[0] == 'ssh'

  #Adding omnibus & bershelf prugins
  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest
  config.berkshelf.enabled = true
  config.berkshelf.berksfile_path = './Berksfile'

  #Chef provisioning
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.add_recipe VM
    chef.custom_config_path = 'Vagrantfile.chef'
    chef.json = {
      :nodejs => {
        :install_method => 'package',
        :npm => '2.13.4'
      }
    }
  end

  #start node app
  config.vm.provision :shell do |s|
    s.privileged = false
    s.inline = 'cd /vagrant && pm2 start pm2.json'
  end
end
```

I visited this thread [Vagrant stuck connection timeout retrying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575261/vagrant-stuck-connection-timeout-retrying) and added the line in my vagrant file to see what was happend

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.gui = true
end
```

after that, [screen shows request login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLRyn.png) and this is where i got stuck, because after type 'vagrant' as login and password nothing happends.

NOTES:

- Im using Windows 10
- Windows Firewall is shutted down
- VM Network is set on NAT

Sorry for my spelling, im not good enough in english.

thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few interesting things in your post:

1. Based on your directory path (`C:\xampp\apache\ecomex\ecomex`) from where you `vagrant up`ed, it would seem you are running xampp. Running vagrant from inside an apache/xampp server config is an interesting idea to say the least. It also makes me think something about xampp may be interfering (is there anything mucking with port 22 or 2222?).
2. Can you boot and ssh into a less customized vagrant box? The one you have provided has a bunch of moving parts, many of which could be to blame.
3. Are you running from an elevated command prompt? (Run As Administrator).
4. Try commenting out (adding `#` to the beginning) the following lines, as they are mucking with ssh:

   ```
   ssh_fix = 'bash -c "BASH_ENV=/etc/profile exec bash"'
   config.ssh.shell = ssh_fix unless ARGV[0] == 'ssh'
   ```

   so that they become

   ```
   #ssh_fix = 'bash -c "BASH_ENV=/etc/profile exec bash"'
   #config.ssh.shell = ssh_fix unless ARGV[0] == 'ssh'
   ```
5. Post the results of `vagrant up --debug` (which can also be output to a file, via `vagrant up --debug > vagrantlog.log`).