# VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX) when starting ubuntu in Virtualbox

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

My operating system is windows 10 64 bit.I want to have ubuntu on my system for some development.

So I have installed VirtualBox and Kept ubuntu v18.04.2 in it.
But while Starting I am getting this error "The native API dll was not found (C:\Windows\system32\WinHvPlatform.dll) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).
VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)."

[image]

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer and like to share with you.

1. Enable Virtualization during your BIOS time
2. Disable the Hyper-V role through Settings(problem faced by me)

   1. Right click on the Windows button and select ‘Apps and Features’.
   2. Select Programs and Features on the right under related settings.
   3. Select Turn Windows Features on or off.
   4. Select Hyper-V and disable it.

Answer (score 4):

It is a known issue when running 64-bit VMs in VirtualBox 6.x on Windows 10.

The culprit is [Windows Defender Application/Device Guard](https://www.reddit.com/r/virtualbox/comments/9mffx4/windows_defender_application_guard_the_secret_vtx/).

- **Method 1**

To disable it go to Local Group Policy Editor (Win+R->gpedit.msc) and **disable** *Turn on Virtualization Based Security*

```
Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Device Guard > Turn on Virtualization Based Security
```

[Disable Virtualization Based Security in Local Group Policy Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQyAt.jpg)

Then you need to run the below commands in **command line as an Administrator**:

```
mountvol X: /s
copy %WINDIR%\System32\SecConfig.efi X:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi /Y
bcdedit /create {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} /d "DebugTool" /application osloader
bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} path "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi"
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} bootsequence {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215}
bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} loadoptions DISABLE-LSA-ISO,DISABLE-VBS
bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} device partition=X:
mountvol X: /d
```

where X: is your unused drive letter (can be any other drive letter)

Reboot you computer and confirm disabling Device Guard and Virtualization Based Security by pressing F3 at boot.
After that your virtual machines will be working again.

- **Method 2**

Another way to disable Device Guard is to use PowerShell script.

Download the script from Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53337

Run the script as an Admin:

```
.\DG_Readiness.ps1 –Disable -AutoReboot
```

Comment: Method 2 didn't work for me but Method 1 worked like a charm. Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer and like to share with you .

1.Enable Virtualization during your BIOS time

2.Disable the Hyper-V role through Settings(problem faced by me)

```
 a)Right click on the Windows button and select ‘Apps and Features’.

 b)Select Programs and Features on the right under related settings.

 c)Select Turn Windows Features on or off.

 d)Select Hyper-V and disable it
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38111013/15374795

This answer belongs to -- credit [Tj Kellie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54055/tj-kellie) please do not add like for me.

Note: open Command Prompt by right click on that and click on "Run as administration".

To turn Hypervisor off, run this from Command Prompt (Admin) (Windows+X):

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

and reboot your computer. To turn it back on again, run:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype on
```

If you receive "The integer data is not valid as specified", try:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

**Important note:** after turning off the Hypervisor and restarting the system it is mandatory to turn on the Hypervisor because with out Hypervisor you can not use the git repository on your windows.

Answer (score -3):

useful page 
mine is Winows 10, just enabling 2 Virutal options which are 'Disable ' during BIOS time by default, has worked smooth.

thanks.