# Vagrant stuck connection timeout retrying (Server refused our key)

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

My vagrant was working perfectly fine last night. I've just turned the PC on, hit vagrant up, and this is what I get:

```
vagrant up                                                                     
Bringing machine 'machine1' up with 'virtualbox' provider...                     
==> machine1: Checking if box 'puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64' is up to date...          
==> machine1: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...                     
==> machine1: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...                  
==> machine1: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...             
    machine1: Adapter 1: nat                                                     
    machine1: Adapter 2: hostonly                                                
==> machine1: Forwarding ports...                                                
    machine1: 22 (guest) => 9180 (host) (adapter 1)                              
    machine1: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)                              
==> machine1: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...                            
==> machine1: Booting VM...                                                      
==> machine1: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...        
machine1: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222                                        
machine1: SSH username: vagrant                                              
machine1: SSH auth method: private key                                       
machine1: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...                 
machine1: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...                 
machine1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...                       
machine1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...                       
machine1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...                       
machine1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...                       
machine1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...                       
machine1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...                       
machine1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...                       
machine1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

When I tried to connect I see this:

```
Using username "vagrant".
Server refused our key
vagrant@127.0.0.1's password:
```

But my key file didn't change. There is similar question [Vagrant stuck connection timeout retrying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575261/vagrant-stuck-connection-timeout-retrying) but there is other reason and it not helped me.

There is ssh-config

```
> vagrant ssh-config                                              
Host machine1                                                     
HostName 127.0.0.1                                              
User vagrant                                                       
Port 2222                                                       
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null                                    
StrictHostKeyChecking no                                        
PasswordAuthentication no                                       
IdentityFile "C:/puphpet/puphpet/files/dot/ssh/id_rsa"          
IdentityFile "C:/Users/alexk/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"   
IdentitiesOnly yes                                              
LogLevel FATAL
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line of code to `C:\HashiCorp\vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.8.5\plugins\guests\linux\cap\public_key.rb`:

`chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

---

**Original block:**

`if test -f ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; then
  grep -v -x -f '#{remote_path}' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.tmp
  mv ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.tmp ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
fi`

**New block:**

`if test -f ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; then
  grep -v -x -f '#{remote_path}' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.tmp
  mv ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.tmp ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
  chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
fi`

I had the same problem and found the above solution [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7610).