# Vagrant ssh 'Warning: Remote connection disconnect.' with Drupal VM on Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: windows, drupal, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a work laptop (Windows 7 Enterprise) that I can't seem to Vagrant Up in.
I'm testing this with www.drupalvm.com so that I know I've got something that 'should' work.

Installed:

- Oracle VM Virtual Box Manager 5.0.20 (a workmate suggested downgrading after errors in a newer version).
- Also VMware workstation 12 Player
- CYGWIN_NT-6.1 2.7.0

On
Vagrant 1.9.2 with vagrant-vbguest:

vagrant up

```html
 vagrant up
Bringing machine 'drupalvm' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> drupalvm: Box 'geerlingguy/ubuntu1604' could not be found. Attempting to fin                             d and install...
    drupalvm: Box Provider: virtualbox
    drupalvm: Box Version: >= 0
==> drupalvm: Loading metadata for box 'geerlingguy/ubuntu1604'
    drupalvm: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/geerlingguy/ubuntu1604
==> drupalvm: Adding box 'geerlingguy/ubuntu1604' (v1.0.9) for provider: virtual                             box
    drupalvm: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/geerlingguy/boxes/ubuntu1                             604/versions/1.0.9/providers/virtualbox.box
    drupalvm:
==> drupalvm: Successfully added box 'geerlingguy/ubuntu1604' (v1.0.9) for 'virt                             ualbox'!
==> drupalvm: Importing base box 'geerlingguy/ubuntu1604'...
==> drupalvm: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> drupalvm: Checking if box 'geerlingguy/ubuntu1604' is up to date...
==> drupalvm: Setting the name of the VM: drupalvm.dev
==> drupalvm: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> drupalvm: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    drupalvm: Adapter 1: nat
    drupalvm: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> drupalvm: Forwarding ports...
    drupalvm: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> drupalvm: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> drupalvm: Booting VM...
==> drupalvm: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    drupalvm: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    drupalvm: SSH username: vagrant
    drupalvm: SSH auth method: private key
    drupalvm: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
# Repeated for a couple minutes, etc..
 drupalvm: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Vagrant up --debug
http://dropcanvas.com/18edq/1

VT-X is definitely enabled, which I checked with the Intel Processor Identification utility.

I also downgraded and got same error with 1.8.6.

I'm sure I was getting a different error earlier? I've been banging my head against this wall for too long.

I used virtual box to look at the GUI as it started up, and the error message started to overwrite itself, but looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as outlined below, I have to go mark Settings > Network ˅ Advanced > 'Cable Connected' because that version of Virtualbox doesn't have it on by default. ?!?!

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15705

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40397387/705790